# How to delete all archived emails?

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

How to delete all archived emails?
I have many of them in the "All mail folder" but they are mixed with other e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Gmail's search bar us the following query: `in:archive`
2. Check the `Select all` check-box
3. Click the `Delete` button* <sup>(*see notes below*)</sup>

###### NOTES

1. Deleting messages does not immediately remove them permanently.  Instead, deleting messages moves them to the [`Trash`](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash) folder.
2. Messages in the [`Trash`](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash) folder can be restored.
3. Messages that have been in `Trash` for more than 30 days will be automatically permanently removed.
4. You can, prior to the expiry of 30 days, permanently remove messages by navigating to the [`Trash`](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash) folder.  There you can select and remove one or more messages, or remove all, by clicking the `Empty Trash now`

**Search `in:archive`**
[image]

**Select All `check-box`**
[image]

**Delete Button**   (*move to* [`Trash`](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash))
[image]

**Permanently Delete**   (*remove from* [`Trash`](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#trash))
[image]

Comment: If you are in conservation view some of the conversations that are still in the inbox will appear on this list, I have 7 of them in the first page of results.

Answer (score -1):

In Gmail, there is no "archive" label.

All emails you sent to "Archive" - Actually removes any other label from it and can be found only later in the "All Mail" label.

.

But I found a way to find only the messages sent to the "archive".

**Write in the search bar:**

```
has:nouserlabels -in:Sent -in:Chat -in:Draft -in:Inbox
```

In the search results you will see all the messages which are not under any label, which is actually all the messages you have ever sent to "Archive".

You can now delete all search results...

Comment: The archive button only removes the inbox label. It keeps all the other labels.

Comment: why is this downvoted? this actually works and correctly solves the question

Comment: this one should be the solution

Answer (score -3):

I just now found a way around it on android at least.

If you sign into your Gmail account through the Microsoft outlook app all of your archived emails will show up in the archive folder and you can bulk delete them.